# Why middleware mixin declared in django.utils.deprecation.py

Tags: python, django, middleware

in path `django.utils.deprecation.py` we have some class about deprecation warning for methods.

in that file we have a class called `MiddlewareMixin`. this class used to write middleware classes. Although not related to deprecation, Why this class wrote in this path?

Comment: I think because it converts "old"-styled middleware to "new-styled" middleware. The "old" middleware was with `process_request` and `process_response`, but the "new" middleware is in essence a decorator over the "layer below". This mixin converts old style (deprecated) to new style.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**In short**: it is a tool to turn *deprecated* middleware into new one, although it has some limitations.

Django's middleware "style" has changed. This `MiddlewareMixin` can in most cases "convert" an old-styled middleware class to a new style middleware *decorator*, as is written in the [documentation on *Upgrading pre-Django 1.10-style middleware*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware):

> **`class django.utils.deprecation.MiddlewareMixin`**
>
> (...)
>
> In most cases, inheriting from this mixin will be sufficient to **make an old-style middleware compatible with the new system** with sufficient backwards-compatibility. The new short-circuiting semantics will be harmless or even beneficial to the existing middleware. In a few cases, a middleware class may need some changes to adjust to the new semantics.

In the "old days" (prior to [django-1.10](/questions/tagged/django-1.10)), middleware was written like:

```
class SomeMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        # ...
        pass

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        # ...
        return response
```

But nowadays, middleware is seen more as some sort of "decorator" around the "underlying middleware", and eventually the view. As specified in the [documentation on the new middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware):

> A middleware can be written as a function that looks like this:
>
> ```
> def simple_middleware(get_response):
>     # One-time configuration and initialization.
>
>     def middleware(request):
>         # Code to be executed for each request before
>         # the view (and later middleware) are called.
>
>         response = get_response(request)
>
>         # Code to be executed for each request/response after
>         # the view is called.
>
>         return response
>
>     return middleware
> ```

By introducing a new "style", you can see the old middleware as "deprecated" itself, which is of course a pity because all middleware that was previously written now would be rendered invalid.

The `MiddlewareMixin` is however capable to convert such *old* middleware in modern middleware, it does this by overriding the `__call__` function, and thus call the `process_request` and `process_response` in between, like we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/deprecation.py):

> ```
> class MiddlewareMixin:
>     def __init__(self, get_response=None):
>         self.get_response = get_response
>         super().__init__()
>
>     def __call__(self, request):
>         response = None
>         if hasattr(self, 'process_request'):
>             response = self.process_request(request)
>         response = response or self.get_response(request)
>         if hasattr(self, 'process_response'):
>             response = self.process_response(request, response)
>         return response
> ```

Here we thus make the object *callable* by overriding the `__call__` function, and thus mimicking how the `def middleware(request)` in the new style works. If however in the old middleware, the `__call__` is overridden as well, then this can of course result in some problems. Furthermore the old style middleware had some functions like `process_view`, `process_exception`, and `process_template_response`, which are no longer used here. But I have the idea that these were not very "popular" anyway.

Comment: This is so confusing.  I thought it was in that package because it *was* deprecated itself, just by judging by that package name.

Comment: @java-addict301: yes I agree, I likely would have done this differently. Although it is easy of course to criticize. The question is whether a different name would be better. Likely `.compatible` is better, although that is just my five cents.